# D3.js: how to make an half-arrow flow map?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps

I'd like to develop a web app to show origin destination data in a flow map. The map would be divided in spatial compartments and flow between those compartments should be represented by half-arrow symbols with the widths proportional to the flow magnitudes. You can find an example of what I want [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhWmU.png). Besides, I'd like my map to be as interactive of possible (like in [this example](https://flowmap.blue/1Oe3zM219uSfJ3sjdRT90SAK2kU3xIvzdcCW6cwTsAuc?v=52.200100,5.202000,7.60,0,0&a=0&b=1&bo=75&c=1&d=1&lt=1&lfm=ALL&col=Default&f=50)).

Do you know if it's possible in D3.js? If not, do you know a javascript library that can achieve that? After some research, I didn't find any answer to my questions. I found some examples of origin-destination maps (like [here](https://github.com/sarahbellum/Canvas-Flowmap-Layer)) but none fits with what I'm looking for.

Thank you for your time,

Jérôme

Comment: It's certainly possible with D3 - though you'd be mostly on your own with designing the arrow drawing function (either with vanilla javascript or things like d3-path) as D3 does not have any built in arrow generators, half or otherwise.

Comment: https://github.com/emeeks/d3-glyphEdges   half arrow

Comment: @TomShanley, nice, I hadn't seen this, might have to use it in a side project.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I will check this out :)

Comment: Does anyone have a link to a tutorial to use these code? https://github.com/emeeks/d3-glyphEdges
I'm a bit stuck :/

Comment: @brb Unfortunately no :/